# Delay load user controls in parent control

Tags: wpf

I have the scenario where I have some User controls Let say they are :

1. CreateStudents
2. CreateTeachers

Each of the User control have their own View model. The datacontext is set in initialization.

I have a main UI where these above User control can be loaded. So setting the datacontext works fine.

**Problem statement**
I have another User control "CreateClass" which is a collection of tabs. From here I can go to the above two user cotrols (Hidden tabs) .

The datacontext is set by two properties in CreateClassViewModel "CreateStudentManager" and "CreateTeacherManager".

This works fine but the issue is when i default open CreateClass UI, the other User controls also load (I guess because they have default constructor).

Because when I open CreateClass I donot want other controls to be loaded. These should be only loaded when they are called from the Create Class UI explictly.

How to achieve this ?

below is sample for one "CreateStudent"

```
<TabItem Header="Students" Visibility="{Binding IsStudentVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                <Grid>
                    <local:UCCreateStudent DataContext="{Binding CreateStudentManager}"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
```

- Girija

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to do it in code, ie. add the local:UCCreateStudent item to the grid on the desired event trigger. Give the grid a name (e.g. x:Name="MyGrid"), then

```
 void OnTrigger(...)
 {
      UCCreateStudent NewStudent = new UCCreateStudent();
      // extra code for setting the datacontext and any other layout properties
      MyGrid.Children.Add(NewStudent);
 }
```

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to add, I am using MVVM pattern. Is there a way then ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on codeproject: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/217022/Delaying-Element-Initialization-for-Collapsed-Cont